# How to do `sed` in Scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I have text that looks like:

```
some random text yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss +00:00
```

What's the easiest way to convert it to:

```
some random text yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+00:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val re = """(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\+00:00)"""
val s = "some random text 1234-56-78 12:34:56 +00:00"
s.replaceAll(re, "$1T$2$3")
// some random text 1234-56-78T12:34:56+00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

With "replaceAll" method:

```
val reg = """(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) ([0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]) (\+\d{2}\:\d{2})"""
"""1984-31-01 21:54:18 +00:00""".replaceAll(reg, "$1T$2$3")
```

We have `> res1: String = 1984-31-01T21:54:18+00:00`. (replace 1984-31-01 21:54:18 +00:00 with the date).

For more infos: [scala api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, recursive formatting with pattern matching.

```
    val s = " some random text 1234-56-78 12:34:56 +00:00 some other random text 2342-34-23 12:23:43 +00:00"

def formatString(s:String):String = {
     val re = """(.+?)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\+00:00)(.+)?""".r
     s match { 
     case null => ""
     case re(prefix,d,t,m,rest) => s"${prefix}${d}T${t}${m}"+formatString(rest)
     case _ => s
     }
  }

scala> formatString(s)
res26: String = some random text 1234-56-78T12:34:56+00:00 some other random text 2342-34-23T12:23:43+00:00
```